# SQL Error in Java but not in SQL

Tags: java, mysql

I have a very odd error, the following query works in the SQL @ phpMyAdmin but not in Java.

I've tested it with the same values in the workbench, or whatever it's called.

The error I get:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select '215406250656137216' as col1, '//' as col2, 'Welcome!' as col3, 'Goodbye!' at line 1

My query:

```
public class Queries {

    public static String checkExistanceQuery = "INSERT INTO guilds(`ID`, `Prefix`, `Join`, `Leave`)" 
+"select col1, col2, col3, col4"
+"from (select '{id}' as col1, '//' as col2, 'Welcome!' as col3, 'Goodbye!' as col4) t"
+"WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM guilds WHERE ID = '{id}');";

}
```

My method:

```
public static void checkExistance(String id) {

    try {

        System.out.println("The ID is: "+id);

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String existanceQuery = Queries.checkExistanceQuery;
        existanceQuery = existanceQuery.replace("{id}", id);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int resultSet = statement.executeUpdate(existanceQuery);
        statement.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {

        System.out.println("[Log] Could not check MySQL guild existance.");
        System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage()+"\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing spaces/newlines in that INSERT...SELECT

Comment: @Vld so pretty much add a /n after every line?

Comment: or just a space. The string you produce looks like `select colfrom tablewhere something`

Comment: @dur Doesn't matter, I fixed it. It turns out I needed a space at the end of each line